# REST Api PUT method dispatch

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

According to [REST design guidelines](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful) it is better to map state changing actions like `activate`, `publish`, `share` to PUT methods body as fields.

Like that:

```
PUT /api/articles/32
{
   "activated": true
}
```

My question is how to dispatch in put method handler in the backend which action is which. 
How do i know if it is "activated" or it is "shared"? Any suggestions?

```
@detail_route(methods=['PUT'])
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # if action == 'activate'
    #    activate()
    # if action == 'publish'
    #    publish()

    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: What about:
PUT /api/articles/32
{
   "status": "activated/published/shared"
}

Comment: @Borjante I guess in this case it will be ok, but im talking about situation when logic really differs. And you have to pass different data.

Comment: Can't understand the situation, you might want to add an example

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to perform some action on the `article`. If you want to do it in a purely REST way you should add some kind of transaction for each action you have. So something like this

```
POST /api/publish-article-transaction
{
   articleId: 2
}

-- Response

{
  publish_article_transaction: {
    id: 123,
    articleId: 2,
    status: ok
  }
}
```

The logic behind the ´POST´ is that you create a transaction object rather than modifying the article itself.

Here is a good answer to your question as well
[REST actions and URL API design considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287734/rest-actions-and-url-api-design-considerations)

Another more general example would be

```
POST /api/article-transaction
{
  action: "publish",
  articleId: 2
}
```

Comment: Agree but still, what i want to understand is in case im using approach with PUT method for updating resource. Where do i need to pass action, is it body, or headers or maybe i can infer that from body itself on backend, which i wont like to do.

Comment: So when you update the article with some properties you want it to have some potential side effect? I.e if you update `article.published = true` you want to execute some publishing action?

Comment: If you want to use `PUT` the action must be inferred by the modification of the article. So everytime you update `published` an email would be sent. I wouldn't really recommend this approach though.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can convert actions like `activate`, `publish` or `share` to resources(nouns) for RESTful urls.

**Article Activation:**

```
PUT /api/article-activation/<pk>/ # activate an article

DELETE /api/article-activation/<pk>/ # deactivate an article
```

**Article Publishing:**

```
PUT /api/article-publication/<pk>/ # publish an article

DELETE /api/article-publication/<pk>/ # unpublish an article
```

**For reference: (Taken from the [article link](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful) you mentioned in comments:)**

> **What about actions that don't fit into the world of CRUD operations?**
>
> This is where things can get fuzzy. There are a number of approaches:
>
> **1.** Restructure the action to appear like a field of a resource. This
>   works if the action doesn't take parameters. For example an activate
>   action could be mapped to a boolean activated field and updated via a
>   PATCH to the resource.
>
> **2.** Treat it like a sub-resource with RESTful
>   principles. For example, GitHub's API lets you star a gist with `PUT /gists/:id/star` and unstar with `DELETE /gists/:id/star`.
>
> **3.** Sometimes you
>   really have no way to map the action to a sensible RESTful structure.
>   For example, a multi-resource search doesn't really make sense to be
>   applied to a specific resource's endpoint. In this case, /search would
>   make the most sense even though it isn't a resource. This is OK - just
>   do what's right from the perspective of the API consumer and make sure
>   it's documented clearly to avoid confusion.

Comment: In this case it is not like a "resource" more of a RPC. I am using following guidelines for designing api http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful

Comment: @VladimirNani Yes, we should not directly add an action. It won't exactly be  RESTful. We should modify our URLs to actually represent a resource  instead of an action in the URL. Updated the ans.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, only a little bit differently, like

```
{"do": "activate"}
```

but it can also be done your way.

First, I created a method on model which did the job, `def activate()`, like setting attribute activated to true. Then in the partial_update method (it's for PATCH, for put it's update (or put, depending on which APIViews you are using)) I retrieved the value like this:

```
action = request.query_params.get('do')
if action == 'activate':
    something.activate()
```

in your case it would be a little bit more different because you just set a parameter "activated" to "true" or false, but you still need this line:

```
activated = request.query_params.get('activated')
```