# API Design, Use RPC for business logic or hide business logic behind resource POST?

Tags: node.js, microservices, api-design

So I usually come to reach the situation where a resource is being edited but it is not simple as changing a field of a certain resource but more of a complex business logic operation like for example:

Lets say we have the resource called:

```
/books/:id
```

Now for any book we can do an operation of putting that book on sale for example. Which behind the scenes will update the boolean field **onSale** for that book (database table *books*) and insert another row in another table called *books_history*

My question is should I hide that business logic behind the POST controller of the **/books/:id** url or should I create a different url and controller for that like **/rpc/putBookOnSale** with the book id and price as parameters ?

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181545/represent-actionsverbs-in-rest-uri shows some possible solutions to this problem.

Comment: This too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287734/rest-actions-and-url-api-design-considerations