# Does using an HTTP resource path as action violate REST standards?

Tags: rest

I'm using an HTTP resource path to execute a backend action instead of providing a resource. An example would be adding a holiday feature to a holiday package on a travel website:

`/holiday/Paris/feature/canal-trip`

In this example the feature `canal-trip` would be added to my planned trip to `Paris`. After this `action` there might be a redirect to the main resource page.

It's clear that this is not strictly a REST resource GET, however I wonder:

- how much this is a REST violation?
- what disadvantages this could cause? (If the action path is not indexed by search engines.)
- what is a better way to provide a path where visitors can execute an action on behalf of a resource?

For this issue let's say **CSRF is not an issue - the action is harmless**. The most similar question I've found is this: [REST actions and URL API design considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287734/rest-actions-and-url-api-design-considerations) - however in my case **I have no intention to make it a real REST endpoint**. Only would like to avoid violations.

Comment: It boils down to trade off between whether you want to provide this endpoint as  a rest api based endpoint for consumers of your product, or you have implemented it just for sake of simplicity of implementation of logistics of your product.

Comment: Let's say the latter one - only for convenience, definitely not putting a real REST resource on the same path.

Answer (score 0):

> how much this is a REST violation?

Pretty hard.  An important part of REST is the notion of a uniform interface -- the idea that consumers and intermediaries don't need to know any details about any specific resource.  That in turn depends on a resource respecting the semantics of the messages that are exchanged.

In the case of HTTP, a GET message is supposed to be [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1); in [2002, Fielding](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html) offered this clarification.

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe. What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the sake of this definition).

.

> what disadvantages this could cause? (If the action path is not indexed by search engines.)

Because the operation is supposed to be safe, any consumer *or intermediary component* is permitted to speculatively fetch the resource.  In your case, that would mean features being added to trips without action by the end consumer.

> what is a better way to provide a path where visitors can execute an action on behalf of a resource?

Use one of the *unsafe* http methods (like POST) to achieve the result you want.