# angular create model for nested JSON data

Tags: angular, typescript, model

I need to create a simple crud using httpclient

How can I get the request data correctly for this nested json?

**JSON**

```
{
    "resource": {
        "date": "2018-03-28T11:30:00",
        "observation": "truck stop schedule",
        "place": "truck garage"
    },
    "errors": null,
    "message": null
}
```

**Service**

```
get(id: number){
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + id + "/stopschedule")
    .catch(this.errorHandler);
}

delete(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete(environment.apiUrl + id + "/stopschedule")    
    .catch(this.errorHandler);
}

update(Travel, id: number) {
    return this.http.put(environment.apiUrl + id + "/stopschedule", Travel)
    .catch(this.errorHandler);
}

errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return Observable.throw(error.message)
}
```

**Model**

```
export class Travel {
    date: Date;
    place: string;
    observation: string;
}


export class ResponseDetails { 
    errors:string;
    message : string; 
}

import { Travel} from './travel';
export class Response extends ResponseDetails{
    travel : Travel; 
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
//Get data
this.getData = this.travelService.get(this.id)
    .subscribe(result => this.data = result['resource'], result =>  this.erro = true);
```

I tried this way but my request is returning an undefined object.

Answer (score 1):

in the service use "map" to change the response

```
get(id: number){
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + id + "/stopschedule")
    .map(response=>response.resource); //NOT return response, just response.resource
    .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` is probably not json body but whole response object so it doesn't contain `resource` property. To retrieve the body from response you need to call `json()` method:

```
this.getData = this.travelService.get(this.id)
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(result => this.data = result['resource'], result =>  this.erro = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API looks strange, but could be only a explanation problem. It makes sense as a response, where errors and message are in the payload, but not as post, and if that is the case, the answer by @krystianpe is the correct way, I must add that if using the new HttpClient the map from json is done automatically if angular can figure out that is a json (response-type: application/json header from server or similar).

Anyway I will quick explain on a way that I think is a better idiomatic REST API:

Creating a new schedule

**POST**: http://localhost/api/schedule
**Body**:  {
        "date": "2018-03-28T11:30:00",
        "observation": "create a new schedule",
        "place": "truck garage"
    }

Return all active schedule

**GET**: http://localhost/api/schedule

If you need filter you have two options:

1. Simplest one is to pass parameters: http://localhost/api/schecule?active=false for example. Use angular URLSearchParams
2. Create Request Headers for more complicated or sofisticated stuff (never saw any). Use HttpHeaders

Editing a schedule:

**PUT**: /api/schedule/1

**Body**: {
        "date": "2018-03-28T11:30:00",
        "observation": "new observation",
        "place": "new place"
    }

You have two options: 
1. Pass the whole object and update all properties (simplest)
2. Pass only the properties who are being altered.

Deleting is as simple as

**Delete**: /api/1

If you need to vinculate what truck has the schedule you put that on the payload (body): {
        "date": "2018-03-28T11:30:00",
        "observation": "new observation",
        "place": "new place",
        "truck_id": 1
    }

To start/stop a schedule, which is your main problem, I think, you have more flexibility. Here are some ways:

**PUT**: /api/schedule/1/start
**PUT**: /api/schedule/1/stop

**PUT**: /api/schedule/1/actions
BODY: {"state": "start", "when": "now"}

PUT is to indicate you are updating somehow the state of system. But that looks like you have a relationship with a "Start" object or "Actions" object and is changing this. So I whould prefer:

**PUT/POST/GET**: /api/schedule/1/actions/start

Use *PUT* to indicate the action is idempotent (which is a confuse word), that changes only the schedule and have no other side effect. Which I think is the case.
Use *POST* to indicate a action which is not idempotent, the side effects are unknow or affect others.
USE *GET* to invoke a action that is ready-only and has not side effects in the system (send a email for example)

You can and should, pass parameters in the body (in this case you are configuring the start parameters), except from GET (makes no sense, use URLParams)

This is explained in more detail in https://github.com/restfulobjects/restfulobjects-spec/blob/2180261f47b7e9279bdb18180ffbee1430b1e342/restfulobjects-spec.pdf?raw=true

There is a discursion in stackoverflow: [REST actions and URL API design considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287734/rest-actions-and-url-api-design-considerations)

Answer (score 0):

If you'r using the `HttpClient` API I'd suggest you change your model to something like this:

```
class ServerResponse<T> {
  resource: T;
  errors: string;
  message: string;
}

class Travel {
  date: Date;
  place: string;
  observation: string;
}
```

Then map your server requests like:

```
get(id: number): Observable<ServerResponse<Travel>>{
    return this.http.get<ServerResponse<Travel>>(`${environment.apiUrl}${id}/stopschedule`);
}
```

Then in your component:

```
this.getData = this.travelService.get(this.id)
    .subscribe(
      result => this.data = result.resource,
      () =>  this.erro = true
    );
```